# How can I hide the label created by jQuery Validator?

Tags: jquery, validation

I am currently applying a simple simple to my validated forms (red background and border) although jQuery validator appends some label with : Field is required.

I just dont want any text to appear.

Thankyou!

Comment: which validator? what is your code?

Comment: Could you please provide the name of the validation plugin that you are using? Also, some sample code will go a long way for you.

Comment: Sorry for the missing information, I am using jQuery Validate Plugin :
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate

 $("#form_commentaire").validate();
jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";

This would do the trick without css .error style that adds a backgournd and border.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could override the [`errorPlacement` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), like this:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) { }
```

Then it simply doesn't append the it's error label element anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use CSS to hide the error labels. E.g.:

```
#login-form label.error {
  display: none !important;
}
```