# Jquery Validation - No Label - add to exisiting element, Can it be done?

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-validate, label

I need some help so Ithink I've come to the right place. What I need is a way to add an error class/ required info class to form fields that arent correct/ valid.

At the moment I have this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform">
    <div class="_required"><p class="label_left">Name*</p>
        <input type="text" size="50" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="required" />
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="_required">
        <p class="label_left">E-mail address*</p>
        <input type="text" size="50" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required email" />
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p class="label_left">Message</p>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" id="message" class="required">
    </textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

With the jquery bit: $("#contactform").validate({

But I dont want the errror appearing in a  or any other element rather in this div in the form:  because I want to wrap it in a background color.

So how do I do this... can it be done?>

Any help or direction would be awesome this is my first taste of Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute the default reporting of the plugin this way:

```
$('#contactform').validate({
            showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {

                //restore the normal look
                $('#contactform div.required').removeClass('required').addClass('_required');

                //stop if everything is ok
                if (errorList.length == 0) return;

                //Iterate over the errors
                for(var i = 0;i < errorList.length; i++)
                    $(errorList[i].element).parent().removeClass('_required').addClass('required');
            }
});
```

Comment: Hola Horacio

Okay I like youre suggestion but I have this problem
<div class="_required"><p class="label_left">Name*</p><input type="text" size="50" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="required" /></div>

to change the class of the containing div...

I guess this may be confusing as I need to have a required class in the <input> for the jQuery. 

So instead, I will now rather call it (class) .xrequired and I need this .xrequired to replace the ._required on the wrapping div

It's probably simple.... but I dont have a clue

Comment: I fixed the code to just reset the class attribute of divs that have the class required. Your inputs class will be untouched.

Comment: Okay so I tried adding the code above between <script type="text/javascript"> </script> and then uploaded the file but I sill get nothing... well if I press submit i get the php error page/ response but it doesnt show the required fields... and if I look with firebug I dont see the added class... even before submit

Comment: Hi Horatio.... bru sorry about that I was being stoopid. I needed to fix the code a bit > see above

Comment: ah just one thing. I now have the thing kind of working but I'd like it to reset back to now being highlighted when the correct data is added> http://www.bgv.co.za/testspace/contact_3.php

Comment: @brett: to reset back the fields you must change the selector (in the first line of the method) to: $('#contactform div.xrequired') since xrequired is the class you set for invalid outputs. Nice design btw.

Comment: Ah yes Horatio! Excellent that sorted it - thank you so much for you help - Yeah I dont know who did this design - I just coded the comp I'm pretty good with the HTML and CSS stuff but quite new to PHP and especially jQuery. But like anything I always learn better by doing

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understood your problem you can do  this

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules#rules

Comment: Hi Praveen, Thank you for your idea. I've tried it out but I'm not really sure what I'm doing... But from what I can see I still get output a <label>etc etc</label> with it. What I'd like to do is push a class into one of my already declared <div class="_required"> to make it <div class="required">

Comment: 1> where is this div placed, 2> what behavior are you expecting from label on error, 3> when do you want this form to display errors to user, on clicking form submit??

Comment: Here is a current view of the form: www.bgv.co.za/testspace/contact_2.php

Comment: 1. Div is in the Form <div class="_required"><p class="label_left">Name*</p>
2. I dont need a message I want to add a background colour to the container div <div class="required"> that wraps the <p>Label</p> and <input field>
3. Yes on submit would be great... although just as data is eneterd would be cool too...

Comment: to hide message from label, put empty message that will eventually  generate empty label. For div to add class: do this>> intercept form on submit, then loop thru each input and and check is it valid or not, if not then check for parent div with class="_required", make that class="required". If u want then i can write this code for you

Comment: Hiya Praveen, man that sounds complicated... I saw this> errorPlacement: function(error, element) { } from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625738/how-can-i-hide-the-label-created-by-jquery-validator as a way to hide the label (That would be great)

But the other bit you mention ( intercept form on submit, then loop thru each input) I would have no clue, if you could help me with the code that would be awesome... I have 2 other forms on the site that have different required areas... so if the code can be recycleable that would eb the cherry on top ... Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

try to add the highlight and unhighlight rule to get highlight error elements

```
 $("#contactform").validate({

        },

        highlight: function (element, errorClass) {                
            $(element).css({ "background-color": "#EE2E24"});
        },

        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
            $(element).css({ "background-color": "#FFFFFF" });
        },

         messages: {
            contactName: "",
            email: "",
            message: ""
        }

 });
```

Comment: Hiya Mahesh,

I've tried this out but I dont get anywhere, for some reason no elements are being changed.

Comment: can you add a message section and try.. i modified the answer

Comment: @Brett: Please add your code to the question, not the answer.

Comment: Hiya Paulo, will do for future. But how can I delete from there now?